# Can I get low level administrative areas from Here Maps?

Tags: maps, gis, here-api

I am trying to get and display low level admnisitrative areas such as neighbourhoods and  disctrictcs via their polygon geometry. I am new to Here Map and GIS. I need this data just for Turkey.

I have read Here documentation, however I could not find a proper solution.

Thanks,,

Comment: Can you provide an example address that you have and the neighborhood data you seek?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do with Platform Data Extension API. You can find description, examples, and details by link https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/what-is.html